# Почему функция не может быть вызвана как конструктор

Tags: javascript

Вопрос, который возник после прочтения [этой](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor) статьи на `MDN`.

Как известно, *любая* функция может быть использована в качестве конструктора, то есть, вызывая её при помощи `new` она будет создавать объекты.

```
const One = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};
const vasya = new One('vasya');
```

Все хорошо. Функция создала пустой объект, через `this` получила ссылку на него, добавила свойство `name`.

Рассмотрим другой пример:

```
const Two = (name) => {
    this.name = name;
};
const petya = new Two('petya');
```

Ничего особенного, кроме:

> Uncaught TypeError: Two is not a constructor(…)

---

**Вопрос:**
Почему во втором примере стрелочная функция не может быть конструктором?
Какова специфика её работы?

Почему стрелочная функция не имеет `[[Prototype]]`?
А что если...

```
Two.prototype = Object.create({
  hasName: () => console.log('Yes, it has a name')
});
Two.prototype.constructor = Two;
```

Не сработает, поскольку `[[Prototype]]` - внутренне свойство, но во имя чего так сделано именно для стрелочных функций?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наследование в `JS` во многом зависимо от `this`.
[Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) во многом урезаны относительно старших братьев, в т. ч. у них нет собственного `this`, что очень удобно для `callback` и они быстры.

---

Но за это надо платить, оптимизация проводится за счет следующих особенностей:

1. `Arrow function` нельзя использовать в качестве конструктора.
2. Переменные `this`, `arguments` и `super` берутся от родительского `function scope`.
3. Внутри `arrow function` нельзя использовать "собственный" объект `arguments` - а это означает, что не надо синхронизировать значения аргументов и псевдо-массива `arguments` .
4. Функции `call`, `apply` и `bind` не могу сменить контекст.

Answer (score 0):

У стрелочных функций нет своего контекста, а this в них - это this из контекста уровнем выше.

В случае с ООП (вернее, попыткой использовать ООП в js), стрелочные функции можно воспринимать как методы класса (который создается обычной функцией). Подробнее здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions